# java.io.FileNotFoundException in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filenotfoundexception

I am having one small app for which i have used spring boot. In this app i read one conf file located in local system disk where this app runs.

```
BufferedReader confFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Tes\\conf.json"));
```

I have a conf.json file in the specified location also. But when i run my spring boot app it says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Tes\conf.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest me what i am missing.

Note: When i run this app from eclipse it runs without an issue.

Comment: Sir round it with a try block, check the permission and unsure anyone can read it. Actually the error is that the file is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Classic BufferedReader

A classic BufferedReader to read content from a file.

### E:\test\filename.txt

```
This is the content to write into file
This is the content to write into file
```

### ReadFileExample1.java

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileExample1 {

    private static final String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\filename.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {

            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

### Output :

```
This is the content to write into file
This is the content to write into file
```

**Resource Link:** [How to read file in Java – BufferedReader](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)